# Copy the elements

Tags: element

I am trying to copy the elements if an atray.

I have written the code below which returns the values stored in src in inverse and I can't find a way to return the elements in dest in the same order:

0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0

Here is my code:

```
.data
         n:        .word 10
     src:      .word 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
     dest:     .space 40    
     i:        .word 0      
     space:   .asciiz " "
         
.text
    main:
    la $t0, src
    lw $t1, i   
    la $t2, dest 
    lw $t4, n    
    
    jal Function_CopytoStack
        
        jal Function_copyfrom_Stack_to_Dest


###############################################
       Function_CopytoStack:          

 ################################################
 ###################
```

Comment: Just FYI, if the source and destination don't overlap, it's a lot more efficient to just copy directly, either reading or writing backwards.  Also, your functions seem to be using `$fp` as a temporary, not treating it as call-preserved like in the standard calling convention. (https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/MIPS_Assembly/Register_File).  Variable-sized stack manipulation is one of the times you might actually want to use `$fp` as a frame pointer.  There are 9 `$t` registers you could have picked instead.  Also, `$a0` is the normal choice for a function arg.

Comment: Or if you don't want to reverse, there's not reason to push one element at a time so your temporary copy is in reverse order.  Just reserve space for the whole array, then copy in a loop.  (And it's even more pointless to use a temporary array; weird assignment.  Hopefully the next step is to write a memmove that works *as if* it used a temporary array, but actually just works with only registers (O(1) space) even for overlapping src and dst.

Answer (score 1):

The second half works by (a) popping one item off the stack, then (b) storing that into an pointer, which starts at the ***beginning*** of the destination and advances ***forward***.

Do the (b) part backwards, to accomplish a double reversal, which will cancel out the first reversal from the stack use.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, yes this is where I got stuck trying to do the (b) part backwards to cancel out the first reverseal.

Comment: So, you get that for that (b) part, at present it starts at the *beginning* and advances the pointer *forwards*, so if you invert both of those, it will reverse the array again.